# Can relative paths be used for @font-face src?

Tags: css, font-face

When using `@font-face` in CSS to use custom fonts, can I specify a relative path for the fonts. Say I have the following structure:

```
WebContent
 - css
    |- style01.css
    |- style02.css
    |- ...
 - fonts
    |- font01.ttf
    |- font01.ttf
    |- ...
 - images
    |- ...
 - js
    |- ...
 - index.html
 - *.html
```

Can I specify something similar to:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'font one';
   src: url('../fonts/font01.ttf');
}
```

since the above does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the issue was that it doesn't like the single quotes `'` around the name.