# Importing font through CSS not working

Tags: css

I apologise in advance as there are a lot of posts that are related, but just can't find a solution.

I'm trying to use a font that I have downloaded, and put in a "fonts" folder. This folder is located where all my webpages are.

The font file is called "timeburnernormal.ttf" and the font name is "TimeBurner"

CSS

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'TimeBurner';
src:url("fonts/timeburnernormal.ttf");
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'TimeBurner';
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:27pt;
}
```

Changing the font family in the h1 class proves successful with any font installed on my computer, but just doesn't work with this method. Is it my CSS?

Thanks

Comment: The fonts path would be relative to the CSS file, so I think you probably need to change it to `src: url("../fonts/timeburnernormal.ttf");`

Comment: didn't try it, but take this into account aswell:

It seems the single quotes in font-family may not help... I don't think so, but give a try

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870699/can-relative-paths-be-used-for-font-face-src

Comment: @MatthewDarnell this solved it thanks very much, feel like an idiot

Comment: @Bob In the future, you might want to examine your web server logs to see what path is being requested for some resource which doesn't seem to make it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If adding the font-family to the h1 directly works, there is a class/id or possibly another h1 declaration in your CSS overruling your font. Take a look at your CSS or inspect the element using Chrome DevTools to see how font family is being set.